# How to view debug logs of locally run AppEngine app in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, debugging, logging, intellij-idea

I have remote debugging set in IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2, which runs a maven goal `clean compile package appengine:run` and connects the debugger on `5005` using the `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` argument.

In the log section of the configuration, I had enabled show logs to the console. I have no log files configured for the server. It only displays to standard out. It displays on normal run which usee `clean compile package appengine:run`. But in debug mode, I don't see any logs. How to view the logs during the debug session?

My `appengine-web.xml` has:

```
 <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
 </system-properties>
```

Comment: Please check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html#logsTab

Answer (score 0):

This is only supported on Intellij IDEA Ultimate edition. check this [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html) please.

Comment: I am using the Cloud Code plugin from Google.

Comment: It explicitly said in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-local#before_you_begin) that running configurations for local run and debug App Engine application are only available for ultimate edition. However, if you are using community edition you can follow the instruction in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-local#community) for debugging Maven or Gradle application in intellij IDEA.